# How to prevent NaN result from custom code in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, report

I want to prevent NaN values when i preview my report (ssrs).
I used custom code.

```
Public Dim TotalAmount As Double = 0
Public Dim ThisValue As Double = 0
Public Dim SValue As Double = 0
Public Dim TValue As Double = 0
Public Function CalculateTotal(FirstValue as Double,SecondValue as Double,
ThirdValue as Double)   as Double
    ThisValue=ThisValue+FirstValue
               SValue=Svalue+SecondValue
               TValue=TValue+ThirdValue
        TotalAmount=SValue/(ThisValue+TValue)*100
    Return TotalAmount
    End Function
```

In my expression:

```
=Code.CalculateTotal(Fields!N_ANSWERED.Value,Fields!SLA.Value,Fields!N_ABANDONED.Value)
```

I tried with prevent dividing by zero :

```
IIF((ThisValue+TValue)*100=0,1,(ThisValue+TValue)*100)
```

, but nothing change.

I expected zero values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just add an If to check for a zero denominator on your TOTAL calculation.

```
Public Dim TotalAmount As Double = 0
Public Dim ThisValue As Double = 0
Public Dim SValue As Double = 0
Public Dim TValue As Double = 0

Public Function CalculateTotal(FirstValue as Double, SecondValue as Double, ThirdValue as Double)   as Double

    ThisValue = ThisValue + FirstValue 
    SValue = Svalue + SecondValue 
    TValue = TValue + ThirdValue

    If ThisValue + TValue <> 0 Then TotalAmount = SValue / (ThisValue + TValue) * 100

    Return TotalAmount

    End Function
```

This way, if your total is 0, it doesn't perform the **Total Amount** calculation.

The IIF that you had was SSRS Expression Syntax not VBA syntax that was probably giving a different error.